# Can't connect to Logitech MX Device with Realtek Bluetooth 4.2 Adapter on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, drivers, bluetooth, arch-linux

*This is a repost from [*my thread on arch forum*](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2095611#p2095611) and [*my reddit post*](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/12rm2uh/cant_connect_to_logitech_mx_device_with_realtek/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)*.

---

Hello,

I'm running on a new fresh install of arch. I use a MX Master 3S Mouse and a MX Keys keyboard from Logitech.
On my previous installation of arch, I could connect to these two devices but on my fresh install it is not working.
The devices appears in the list of available devices, I try to connect and the connection fails.
My Wifi + Bluetooth board is a [rtl8821ce](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:0bda-b00a).

I tried to install [rtl8821ce-dkms-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rtl8821ce-dkms-git) from AUR but I had the following error :

```
ERROR: Missing 6.2.10-arch1-1 kernel headers for module rtl8821ce/1.0.5.r153.ga3e2f7c.
```

Here's some information about my config :

**Arch version**

```
$ uname -r
6.2.11-arch1-1
```

**journalctl after connection failure**

```
$ journalctl -b --no-hostname | grep -i blue 
Apr 19 09:36:26 systemd[721]: Started Add Bluetooth Device - Add Bluetooth Device.
Apr 19 09:36:29 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected cc 0x0c7c length: 1 < 3
Apr 19 09:36:29 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x08 from db:63:24:aa:10:cc
Apr 19 09:36:29 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x09 from db:63:24:aa:10:cc
```

**bluetooth service**

```
$ systemctl status bluetooth.service    
● bluetooth.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit bluetooth.service is masked.)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-04-19 09:35:59 CEST; 25min ago
   Main PID: 60046 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
        CPU: 160ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─60046 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Apr 19 09:36:00 archlinux bluetoothd[60046]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05
Apr 19 09:36:00 archlinux bluetoothd[60046]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05
Apr 19 09:36:00 archlinux bluetoothd[60046]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05_duplex
Apr 19 09:36:00 archlinux bluetoothd[60046]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_duplex
Apr 19 09:36:30 archlinux bluetoothd[60046]: src/service.c:service_accept() input-hog profile accept failed for DB:63:24:AA:10:CC
Apr 19 09:37:01 archlinux bluetoothd[60046]: src/device.c:set_wake_allowed_complete() Set device flags return status: Invalid Parameters
Apr 19 10:00:59 archlinux bluetoothd[60046]: src/service.c:service_accept() input-hog profile accept failed for DB:63:24:AA:10:CD
Apr 19 10:01:01 archlinux bluetoothd[60046]: src/device.c:set_wake_allowed_complete() Set device flags return status: Invalid Parameters
```

**lspci** *(01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter)*

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G7 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Processor Power and Thermal Controller (rev 03)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP DRAM Controller (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Management Engine (rev 30)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 30)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 34bf (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Blue SN500 / PC SN520 NVMe SSD (rev 01)
```

**lsusb** *(Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b00a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Realtek Bluetooth 4.2 Adapter)*

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub             
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 17e9:4301 DisplayLink USB3.0 to HDMI Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0d8c:0014 C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A)
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 046d:c07d Logitech, Inc. G502 Mouse
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 14cd:8601 Super Top 4-Port hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. KB216 Wired Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 30c9:0013 Luxvisions Innotech Limited HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b00a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Realtek Bluetooth 4.2 Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**dmesg**

```
$ dmesg | grep "Blue*"
[    2.098322] usb 1-10: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[    2.886056] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.886071] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.886074] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.886075] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.886077] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.222332] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8821
[    3.223757] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[    3.223761] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_fw.bin
[    3.228407] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_config.bin
[    3.229500] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 10, total sz 34926
[    3.720749] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x75b8f098
[    3.722600] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.722602] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.722605] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.076612] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[   59.350635] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   59.350654] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   59.350665] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   80.991133] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected cc 0x0c7c length: 1 < 3
[   81.039643] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x06 from db:fe:d1:12:97:f4
[   81.082998] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x07 from db:fe:d1:12:97:f4
[   81.083011] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x08 from db:fe:d1:12:97:f4
[   81.083014] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x09 from db:fe:d1:12:97:f4
[  111.858446] Bluetooth: hci0: No such LE device db:fe:d1:12:97:f4 (0x1)
[  115.119075] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected cc 0x0c7c length: 1 < 3
[  115.167612] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x08 from db:63:24:aa:10:c8
[  115.210973] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x09 from db:63:24:aa:10:c8
[  145.644525] Bluetooth: hci0: No such LE device db:63:24:aa:10:c8 (0x1)
[  188.834835] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected cc 0x0c7c length: 1 < 3
[  188.860961] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x06 from db:fe:d1:12:97:f5
[  188.884286] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x07 from db:fe:d1:12:97:f5
[  188.884299] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x08 from db:fe:d1:12:97:f5
[  188.884302] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x09 from db:fe:d1:12:97:f5
[  218.931116] Bluetooth: hci0: No such LE device db:fe:d1:12:97:f5 (0x1)
[ 1931.368431] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000092630f52 failed to resubmit (2)
[ 1931.637828] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=75b8 lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=f098
[ 1931.957131] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8821
[ 1931.957951] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[ 1931.957959] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_fw.bin
[ 1931.963652] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_config.bin
[ 1931.964231] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 10, total sz 34926
[ 1932.430992] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x75b8f098
[ 1932.498227] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[ 1984.630882] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected cc 0x0c7c length: 1 < 3
[ 1984.680208] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x08 from db:63:24:aa:10:c9
[ 1984.723413] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x09 from db:63:24:aa:10:c9
[ 2011.438704] Bluetooth: hci0: No such LE device db:63:24:aa:10:c9 (0x1)
[ 2172.867902] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected cc 0x0c7c length: 1 < 3
[ 2172.916008] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x08 from db:63:24:aa:10:ca
[ 2172.959346] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x09 from db:63:24:aa:10:ca
[ 2198.696877] Bluetooth: hci0: No such LE device db:63:24:aa:10:ca (0x1)
[ 3003.560859] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected cc 0x0c7c length: 1 < 3
[ 3003.610673] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x08 from db:63:24:aa:10:cb
[ 3003.657343] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x09 from db:63:24:aa:10:cb
[ 3034.766966] Bluetooth: hci0: No such LE device db:63:24:aa:10:cb (0x1)
[ 3111.666820] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000b86015ba failed to resubmit (2)
[ 3111.735758] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=75b8 lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=f098
[ 3112.054126] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8821
[ 3112.054821] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[ 3112.054826] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_fw.bin
[ 3112.062106] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_config.bin
[ 3112.063286] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 10, total sz 34926
[ 3112.530105] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x75b8f098
[ 3112.596165] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[ 3141.715103] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected cc 0x0c7c length: 1 < 3
[ 3141.761886] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x08 from db:63:24:aa:10:cc
[ 3141.808547] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x09 from db:63:24:aa:10:cc
[ 3172.915389] Bluetooth: hci0: No such LE device db:63:24:aa:10:cc (0x1)
[ 4610.777871] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected cc 0x0c7c length: 1 < 3
[ 4610.826599] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x08 from db:63:24:aa:10:cd
[ 4610.870170] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x09 from db:63:24:aa:10:cd
[ 4613.526402] Bluetooth: hci0: No such LE device db:63:24:aa:10:cd (0x1)
```

All the following solutions didn't work :

1. Manually build and install the `rtl8821ce-dkms-git`
2. Build and upgrade to latest version of `linux-firmware` package
3. Disable USB auto-suspend for the bluetooth card.
4. Use the kernel provided `rtw88` driver
5. Use `bluetoothctl trust [device mac]` before pairing
6. Restart bluetooth service
7. Use new Logitech "Bolt" dongle included with MX Master 3S mouse and pair with `solaar` : keeps disconnecting.
8. Do a full system upgrade with `pacman -Syu`
9. Check if the bluetooth device was soft or hard blocked with `sudo rfkill list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT : solved by using `linux-lts` kernel instead of `linux` kernel ! I'm now on `6.1.25-1-lts`.